# Shell, IFS, read and tabulation

Tags: bash, shell, ifs

I'm trying to read a TSV file in a shell script, and found that when IFS is set to tabulation, read skip null values. An exemple is better than 1000 word:

```
$ echo -e "a\tb\tc" | while IFS=$'\t' read v1 v2 v3; do echo "$v1 - $v2 - $v3"; done
a - b - c
```

This work as expected

```
$ echo -e "a\t\tc" | while IFS=$'\t' read v1 v2 v3; do echo "$v1 - $v2 - $v3"; done
a - c -
```

I would have expected to have $v2 set to null, and $v3 to "c"

```
$ echo -e "a||c" | while IFS=$'|' read v1 v2 v3; do echo "$v1 - $v2 - $v3"; done
a -  - c
```

With | as delimiter, $v2 get a null value and $v3 get value "c" as I'm expecting.

Anyone has an explanation about the different behavior when using | or \t ? And a way to have \t behave like for | ?

Comment: consecutive white space characters (`space`, `tab`, `newline`) are treated as a single delimiter (see [gnu/bash/word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html); this 'rule' does not apply to non-white space characters used as a delimiter (eg, `|`); see the last part of KamilCuk's answer for one method of getting around `bash's` default behavior of combining consecutive white space characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anyone has an explanation about the different behavior when using | or \t ?

From [posix read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/read.html):

> The line shall be split into fields as in the shell (see [Field Splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05)); the first field shall be assigned to the first variable var, the second field to the second variable var, and so on. If there are fewer var operands specified than there are fields, the leftover fields and their intervening separators shall be assigned to the last var. If there are fewer fields than vars, the remaining vars shall be set to empty strings.

So let's go to [posix shell field splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) (emphasis mine):

> The shell shall treat each character of the IFS as a delimiter and use the delimiters to split the results of parameter expansion and command substitution into fields.
>
> 1. If the value of *IFS* is a `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>`, or if it is unset, ... [doesn't apply here]
> 2. If the value of *IFS* is null, ... [also doesn't apply here]
> 3. Otherwise, the following rules shall be applied in sequence. The term "IFS white space" is used to mean any sequence (zero or more instances) of white space characters that are in the IFS value (for example, if *IFS* contains `<space>`/ `<comma>`/ `<tab>`, any sequence of `<space>`s and `<tab>`s is considered IFS white space).
>
>    1. IFS white space shall be ignored at the beginning and end of the input.
>    2. **Each occurrence** in the input of an *IFS* character **that is not IFS white space**, along with any adjacent *IFS* white space, shall delimit a field, as described previously.
>    3. **Non-zero-length *IFS* white space** shall delimit a field.

When `IFS` is set to any combination of whitespaces, then these whitespaces are concatenated together when splitting fields (ie. the "non-zer-length").

So `echo -e "a\t\tc" | IFS=$'\t' read v1 v2 v3` is equal to `echo -e "a\t\t\t\t\tc" | IFS=$'\t' read v1 v2 v3`. Because there are "are fewer fields than vars" (2 vs 3), `v3` is set to empty string.

But when `IFS` is set to anything else then whitespace, then **each occurence** of that `IFS` characters splits fields.

Yet another funny corner case, where whitespace characters are treated specially.

> And a way to have \t behave like for | ?

In bash, replace it for something unique before reading. I like to use `0x01` byte:

```
echo -e "a\t\tc" |
    tr '\t' $'\x01' |
    while IFS=$'\x01' read -r v1 v2 v3; do echo "$v1 - $v2 - $v3"; done
```

Remember to use `read -r`.